# Count how many different values a list takes in Mathematica

Tags: count, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to get the number of different values found in a List.

For example:

The output for the List `a={1,2,3,4,5}` would be 5 whereas it would be 2 for `b={1,1,1,2,2}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just for amusement, all the following commands also give the desired result:

```
Length@Gather@l

Length@Union@l

Length@Tally@l

Count[BinCounts@l, Except@0]

Count[BinLists@l, Except@{}]

Length@Split@Sort@l

Length@GatherBy[l, # &]

Length@Split@SortBy[l, # &]
```

And many more, of course.

**Edit**

Here is a little timing experiment (not serious)

```
l = RandomInteger[{1, 10^2}, 10^7];
t2[x_] := {Timing[x], ToString[HoldForm@x]};
SetAttributes[t2, HoldAll]
Grid[Reverse /@
  {t2[Length@DeleteDuplicates[l]],
   t2[Length@Tally[l]],
   t2[Length@Gather[l]],
   t2[Count[BinCounts[l], Except@0]],
   t2[Length@Union[l]],
   t2[Length@Split@Sort@l],
   t2[Count[BinLists[l], Except@0]]},
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

BTW: Note the difference between `BinLists[ ]` and `BinCounts[ ]`

**Edit**

A more detailed view of `DeleteDuplicates` vs `Tally`

```
t = Timing;
ListLinePlot@Transpose@
  Table[l = RandomInteger[{1, 10^i}, 10^7];
   {Log@First@t@Length@DeleteDuplicates@l,
    Log@First@t@Length@Tally@l},
   {i, Range[7]}]
```

Beware! Log Plot!

[image]

Comment: Thank you Belisarius ! What would be your favorite ? Fastest ?

Comment: @500 As it was mentioned before,`DeleteDuplicates[ ]` is the fastest AFAIK. These are just for showing to the OP some other ways to do the same.

Comment: @Belisarius, as Sjoerd only compared it to union I was not sure about your other solution, thank you !

Comment: @Belisarius : This is impressive. I also discover that very elegant HoldForm, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) (or `Union` in older versions) to remove duplicate elements. You can then count the elements in the returned list.

```
In[8]:= Length[DeleteDuplicates[a]]
Out[8]= 5

In[9]:= Length[DeleteDuplicates[b]]
Out[9]= 2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Length[DeleteDuplicates[a]]
```

would do the trick.  Depending on what else you're going to do, you could use `Union` or `Tally` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: It may be good to note that DeleteDuplicates can be 20 times as fast as Union. Union returns a sorted list whereas DeleteDuplicates keeps the resulting values in their original order.

Comment: @Sjoerd, great point.  It can be far more, if the list is mostly duplicates.  Try: `RandomInteger[999, 150000]`.

Comment: @Sjoerd, @Mr.Wizard What you observed is entirely due to the packed nature of the data on which this is so. If we take @Mr's example `rnd = RandomInteger[999, 150000];` and do `rnd[[100000]] = 1/2;`, and then do the benchmarks, `DeleteDuplicates` is still faster but only by a factor of `3` or so, which is probably due to its linear complexity as compared to the `n log n` complexity of `Union`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CountDistinct[a]
```

would also do the trick, which is a function introduced in Mathematica 10.0, a function equivalent to

```
Length[DeleteDuplicates[a]]
```